# Javascript regex replace between closing and opening tags

Tags: javascript, regex, tags, replace

I realise this must be a really easy piece of regex, but just can't seem to work it out. I just need to search a string for this:

```
</p><p>
```

And add a comma between them, like this:

```
</p>,<p>
```

Ignore the fact it isn't nice html, it makes sense to me though!

I tried this, but didn't seem to work:

```
str.replace(/<\/p><p>/g, "</p>,<p>");
```

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: `"</p><p>".replace(/<\/p><p>/g, "</p>,<p>"); // => "</p>,<p>"` works just fine in chrome 12. Which Javascript platform are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault. It does work. I'd forgotten that I have ids in each p tag, so just needed to search for this:

```
/<\/p><p/g
```

Thanks for all the replies though!

Answer (score 2):

> I tried this, but didn't seem to work:
>
> `str.replace(/<\/p><p>/g, "</p>,<p>");`

[`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) *returns a new string* with the result, it doesn't modify the string you called it on. So that would be:

```
    str = str.replace(/<\/p><p>/g, "</p>,<p>");
//  ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
alert("Some </p><p> to replace".replace(/<\/p><p>/g, "</p>,<p>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/eBkhR/

Comment: You're right. My fault. My strings actually had ids in the <p> tags, so just needed to search for /<\/p><p/g.

Comment: @WastedSpace, thats why you shouldn't parse HTML with regex. ~.~

Comment: @Wasted: You might as well post that as an answer and accept it.  As long as it doesn't have an accepted answer, this Q/A will get revived every so often by the "Community" pseudo-user.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in javascript are immutable. That is, the contents in a string cannot be modified. Therefore, when using `replace` method it cannot replace the content but it just returns a new string with the new contents. You would need to store the new string the in required variable.

for example,

```
str = str.replace(/<\/p><p>/g, "</p>,<p>");
```

The answers with `alert` will work because the new string is getting passed to the `alert` function. The string itself is not modified.